# Adding "Link to Document" to all document libraries in SharePoint 2010

Tags: document-library, content-type

Is there a way to add the "Link to Document" content type to all existing document libraries in a site/site collection other than editing each one manually?  I'm fine to do it with PowerShell if there is a way.

Also is there a way to change the template for the default document library so that all new document libraries will have this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

This is untested, but I'd probably do something like this:

```
$site = get-spsite http://your/site

$rootWeb = $site.RootWeb

$linkToDocCType = $rootWeb.AvailableContentTypes["Link to a Document"]

foreach ($web in $site.AllWebs)
{
    foreach ($list in $web.Lists)
    {
        if ($list.BaseType -eq [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPBaseType]::DocumentLibrary)
        {
            $listMatchCTypeId = $list.ContentTypes.BestMatch($linkToDocCType.Id)

            if (!$listMatchCTypeId.IsChildOf($linkToDocCType.Id))
            {
                $webCTypeCopy = $list.ParentWeb.AvailableContentTypes[$linkToDocCType.Id]
                $listCTypeCopy = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContentType($webCTypeCopy, $list.ContentTypes, $webCTypeCopy.Name)
                $list.ContentTypes.Add($listCTypeCopy)
                $list.Update()
            }
        }
    }

    $web.Dispose()
}

$rootWeb.Dispose()
$site.Dispose()
```

As far as your second question, about changing the default document library template to always include "Link to a Document", I really don't know.  It may be possible, but then again it's my understanding that it's a best-practice to leave the OOB stuff alone and not customize it, as an update from Microsoft might overwrite your customization.